MATCH formula with multiple conditions returning true when false
The formula below returns True ("Issue") when only the first condition is True (COUNTIF(Table1[Boss ID]) when it should return false as the other conditions in the rest of the formula are false.
Not sure if the * is working correctly in this formula and if maybe an AND function should be used.
This formula is applied on an online Excel document.
=IF(COUNTIF(Table1[Boss ID], A13)*OR(COUNTIF(Table1[Result],"Sample haemolysed."),COUNTIF(Table1[Result],"Insufficient Sample"),COUNTIF(Table1[Result],"Sample Insufficient."),COUNTIF(Table1[Result],"Sample Insufficient for FBC.")),"Issue", "No Issue")


It would help to see some sample data and expected output.

I would "outsource" the results that create an issue. Then you can use this formula:
=LET(BossID,D2,
filterResults,FILTER(Tabelle1[Result],Tabelle1[Boss ID]=BossID),
IF(
    SUM(--ISNUMBER(MATCH(filterResults,tblIssues[issue],0)))>0,
    "Issues","no Issue"
  )
)



That works great thank you very much!

The result you're getting is:

COUNTIF(Table1[Boss ID], A13) etc. > count the whole column and return a single result
but we want to get counts row by row - swapping the condition would do it

`COUNTIF(A13, Table1[Boss ID])
for the others, the strings need to be in cells as COUNTIF expects a range as the first argument
so COUNTIF(Table1[Result],"Sample haemolysed.") would be COUNTIF(A15, Table1[Result]) with "Sample haemolysed." in A15


Also, when you use OR, the result is a single value; by using + we get a row-wise OR, as in

COUNTIF() + COUNTIF()...




Ike's answer is a good solution.
Here's another way by adding a column to your table, and add two tables for BOSS Ids and reasons to check:
Formula to enter in the first cell of the "Issue?" column:
=IF(OR(
ISNUMBER(XMATCH([@[BOSS ID]],CheckBoss[ID])),
ISNUMBER(XMATCH([@Result],CheckReason[Reason]))),
"Issues","no Issue")


